# How to list a process that contains spaces in the name

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a batch that checks whether the process is active and if it is closed it ... the point is that when the process has spaces in the name it is not found.

```
Set "EXE=Process name.exe">nul 2>&1
FOR /F %%x IN ('tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq %EXE%"') DO IF %%x == %EXE% Taskkill /F /IM "%EXE%" >nul 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should handle the spaces in the code, depending on what the first tasklist prints:

```
Set "EXE=Process name.exe"
FOR /F "delims=" %%x IN ('tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq %EXE%"') DO IF /i "%%x" == "%EXE%" Taskkill /F /IM "%EXE%" >nul 2>&1
```

This is another way of doing it:

```
Set "EXE=Process name.exe"
tasklist|find /i "%EXE%" >nul && Taskkill /F /IM "%EXE%" >nul 2>&1
```

and this is functionally equivalent: it will only kill the task if it exists.

```
Set "EXE=Process name.exe"
Taskkill /F /IM "%EXE%" >nul 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wmic process where name="Process name.exe" get Name,ProcessId
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Try, putting quotes around your process name like

```
Set EXE="Process name.exe" >nul 2>&1
```